Convert image from longblob database to angular image
I am developing a code that receives several images from a byte[] database.
@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="LONGBLOB")    
private byte[] image;

My problem comes when I try to display those images in a web application because I can't find a way to convert them to a valid URL.
What I have at the moment is this:
export interface pastEvent {
    description: string;
    title: string;
    image: string;
    imageUrl?: SafeUrl;
}

this.eventService.getLastEvents().subscribe((events: pastEvent[]) => {
    this.lastEvents = events.map(event => {
        const imageUrl = this.formatImage(event.imagen);
            return {
                ...event,
                imageUrl
            }
        })
    });
}

I've tried transforming it to base64 this way but it doesn't work.
formatImage(image: string) {
    let objectURL = 'data:image/webp;base64,' + image;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);
}

Using that, the URL with all bytes of the image appears in the element inspector, but the image is not displayed. It appears as follows:
<img src="data:image/webp;base64,eNqU....’

